# How to view directed acyclic graphs as output in scilab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, scilab

I have to implement a graph algorithm on a directed acyclic graph in scilab.

How can I show the output graph in output window? Do I need to create a GUI?

Answer (score 1):

There is a module/toolbox called Metanet, see http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/metanet/0.6.1, that you can use.

It specifically has a function show_graph that should solve your problem. You can also highlight arcs and nodes using show_arcs and show_nodes.

Further, depending on which algorithm you're implementing, you might be able to verify its correctness by using the corresponding function in the toolbox :-)